# ssis 2015 excel Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager ‘Excel Connection Manager’

Tags: excel, ssis

we've got a Windows Server 2012 R2 with SSIS 2015 installed, and also SAP BO BI 4.2. There is also Office 2016, and we first tried (and then uninstalled) Microsoft Office Access Redistributable 2010 32bit (which had some problems with BO), and then we successfully installed Microsoft Office Access Redistributable 2016 32bit.

Before the redistributable, the SSIS couldn't even see the Excel component in the data flow. We are accessing with some users in RD to the machine, and there is a user which is administrator.

So, the administrator made all the install/uninstall. If we open a SSIS solution with the administrator, and we open a DTSX with an Excel connection, it hangs. If we try to make a new SSIS to point to a new Excel, when we try to open the table we get "Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager ‘Excel Connection Manager’". That also happens to some of my collegues.

***What is extremely strange, is that this doesn't happen to my user***. I can connect to the RD, open the SSIS solution, and all the metadata is loaded. I can create a new DTSX, point to the same Excel on the server, and I see the sheets to choose. Somehow, I guess, my user is the only one which is loading correctly the dlls for Access 2016 (if I try to set a different driver, it doesn't load).

I'll try when I get back to work to see if the suggestion here to read from SQL and see if I get the same error from the other users is always the same...but still I need to get why my user is working.
https://mariussqlbi.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/extracting-data-from-excel-with-ssis/

Any help would be appreciated...

Daniele

Comment: You really need some white space in your question.

Comment: I needed some more CR/LF, didn't noticed it  :)...added them